# Cost Map 2D Setup

Tags: ros, navigation, sonar, costmap-2d, costmap-2d-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm still trying to figure out a way to generate a reasonable map using sonar data alone. I've given up on gmapping for now.

Thought I'd look at the navigation stack's cost map 2d - questions I have are:

1. Do I/can I just write a node only creating a cost map 2d like in section 3 in  http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d

2)Or would I be better off just setting up the navigation stack as per http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42743/cost-map-2d-setup/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-20**:
Which one you find it efficient to use? Can the robot be able find out it's coordinate position from the global cost map?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2013-10-21**:
Hi Brian - thus far I've had no luck with either giving me any kind of representation of the environment. Which is kind of a shame because software I've written myself can generate a reasonable map - true no where near as good as a laser etc but I am able to see boundary and object outlines

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-24**:
http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData

go through this link it might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run just the costmap in a node without the other parts of navigation by running `rosrun costmap_2d costmap_2d_node` after you have set the appropriate parameters on the parameter server.

However, this method relies on having the proper transforms in place, i.e. very accurate odometry.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1